# Dates do not post right

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetime

I seem to be going no place fast...

Can't seem to get a single inline(embeded) jquery Datepicker dateText to post to the PHP and mysql correctly to return data from the table.. My reading has me to understand it should be right, but it is not. Now the datepicker select does have several events that trigger from the single select... data being requsted by the day, month, and year as well as sending the date to create a highcharts graph of data for hours of a day, days of a month, and months of a year.

The Table is very simple... date, time, power

Here is the Javasctipt...

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
        $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
        $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));
        $.post('dayPower.php', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
            $('#apDiv2').html(data).show();
        });
        $.post('dayGraph.php', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
              $('#apDiv4').html().show();
        });
        $.post('monthPower.php', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
            $('#apDiv6').html(data).show();
        });
        $.post('monthGraph', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
              $('#apDiv9').html().show();
        });
        $.post('yearPower.php', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
            $('#apDiv8').html(data).show();
        });
        $.post('yearGraph', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
              $('#apDiv10').html().show();
        });
  }});
```

});

Here is the PHP for the POST for getting the data for the day (dayPower.php)...

```
    <?
if(isset($_POST['choice']))
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxx"); 
if (!$con)  { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con); 

$sql = 'SELECT sum(power) AS power '        
.'FROM feed '       
.'WHERE date = $choice';
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['power']; 
?>
```

The first and second line of the PHP should get the date from the datepicker, and then put it into a date mysql can read, and the sql select should get the values from the table and echo it into the DIV where I have told it to go... What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,

ALan

I now have the Jquery to post to the PHP file with this script...

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
        $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
        $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));
        $('#apDiv2').load('dayPower.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
              $(this).show();
        });
        $('#apDiv4').load('dayGraph.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
              $(this).show();
        });
        $('#apDiv6').load('monthPower.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
              $(this).show();
        });
        $('#apDiv9').load('monthGraph', {choice: dateText}, function() {
              $(this).show();
        });
        $('#apDiv8').load('yearPower.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
              $(this).show();
        });
        $('#apDiv10').load('yearGraph', {choice: dateText}, function() {
              $(this).show();
        });
  }});
```

});

As the new structure is using LOAD and not POST, my understanding is that I must use GET in the PHP, so I have made the changes that I understand should work, but they do not... I seem to be back in the same boat as before... here is the new PHP... Any ideas to why it does not work ????

```
<?  
$choice = (isset($_GET['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
}  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);   
$sql = 'SELECT sum(power) AS choice '         
.'FROM feed '        
.'WHERE date = $choice'; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
echo $row['choice'], '<br />';  
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: Do you get anything if you just var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: I have not tried that.. I have been using print_r to debug. I have never used var_dump($_POST) before.

Comment: YOU SHOULD! `print_r` is for lazy viewing, only `var_dump` will print the actual input/output

Answer (score 1):

How is the date picker formatting the date selected?  All of my experience with JS date pickers returns human-readable dates, not the UNIX timestamps that I would assume you are using in your database.  In that case you can use `$choice_timestamped = strtotime($choice);` on the date string from the date picker then the `date()` function when outputting it to display in whatever format you like.

Comment: The datepicker is mm-dd-yy, and my understanding is that.. $choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); will make the date how the database needs.

Comment: The date is just being used to collect data, and output that data from the table. no date in being returned to the DIV, only the data for the selected date. You can see what I am trying to do at www.pvmonitor.000a.biz/demo2.php

Comment: The way you have it set up with that ternary, you should get a valid query either way, searching for either the selected date or the current date.  This may or may not be desirable behavior, but since you put it in there I'll go with the former.  So where are you getting an error?  The first suggestion would be the first place I would start.

Comment: In the post function where you are changing the div contents with the return data, put an alert(data); as well, to see if you are getting any call back at all.  This will also help if you are echoing any debug info in the php script.

Comment: Yes, I try that a few times a day thinking that would assist me, but always the same..

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you're using `dateText.val`. It seems to me that according to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onSelect), `dateText` is just a string:

> The function receives the selected
>   date as text and the datepicker
>   instance as parameters.

Now, the second parameter to the function is the input element. This is probably what you want to call `.val()` on (note the brackets as well).

Try changing:
`$('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText) {`
To: `$('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText,inst) {`
And then change any `dateText.val` to `inst.val()`.

Comment: OK, tried that and also went to Jquery documentation... I learned a lesson there, but var_dump in the php is still not puting anything into the div. hmmm I have made the script struucture as simple as I can but always the same result.

Comment: Try showing your div's by default (instead of using `.show()`) and see if anything changes. Also, try setting an alert in the `onSuccess` and `$.post` call back functions, just to make sure that they're running.

Comment: Also, if `$_POST['choice']` is not set, it seems that `$choice` will never be defined because you have that `if` statement above it. You'll also want to put single quotes around `$choice` in your query since it's a string.

Comment: Oh and just a note, if you keep timestamps on your dates in the database (ie. you store "2010-10-27 13:15:00") and you select `WHERE date = '2010-10-27'`, these are not the same since the times don't match (I believe '2010-10-27' = '2010-10-27 00:00:00').

Comment: The date from my device puts it into the database table with date in 1 column and time in another column, so they are date='2010-11-30' and time='00:00:00' and not a single timestamp '2010-11-30 00:00:00'. I have single quotes around $choice, where do you see different ?

Comment: Like this: `.'WHERE date = \'$choice\'';`

Comment: I get it, the single quotes tell the sql that the date is a string... OK, good effort, but same result.

Comment: It seems that the date is not getting into the dayPower.php file. I am at a loss of ideas, and from everything I read it should be getting there.

Comment: @hkalan2007 - Is your date input visible? Do you see it changing? Did you try doing the alerts like I suggested?

Comment: Hello, No date at all.. I have done the alert, I have been trying to debug wih print_r, var_dump... For some reason I really think the jquery POST is not sending to the PHP... It does not seem to do anything for the dayPower.php, it should be sending something. I know the datepicker is working because when I select a date, the actual dates show on the page with every date selection, so I know the datepicker fuction is sending the dateText, but the post is not happening... So odd.

Comment: @hkalan2007 - Perhaps you're getting an XMLHttpRequest error. Try changing it to the full `$.ajax` method and add an error callback:

Comment: `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: url, data: data, success: success, dataType: dataType, error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); } });` Note: I took most of that from the docs so you'll have to sub in your info.

Comment: I just made an edit to my question at the top of the page, I now have the jquery to post to the PHP, now to get the PHP working !!!

Comment: Try what I said about using `inst.val()`.

Comment: When I try that, there is nothing from the PHP file in the div... right now I only have HI written in the PHP file and HI will show in the div when I select a date in the datepicker... if I use inst.val() in the Jquery, I get nothing from the php file. As of right now the jquery script is posting to the php file... The date from the jquery is formatted to yyyy-mm-dd so mysql should have no trouble to read the date.

Comment: Jquery documentation says The inst parameter to onSelect is the datepicker instance object, which doesn't have a val function. SO now to wrap my head around the PHP script to get that to work !!

Comment: @hkalan2007 - Aha, beat at my own game with the docs. `.load` uses use GET not POST, so you'll have to switch `$_POST` in your php to `$_GET`. Also, I think you should remove the first line: `if(isset($_POST['choice']))` which is redundant since you check it in the following line anyways.

Comment: Hello, The docs are teaching me a thing or two, but the PHP seems to be my only headache now. I am now using the GET, and lost the first line, but the result is the same... an empty div...

Comment: Try adding `echo 'Choice:'.$choice;` after you define the `$choice` variable. Also, try going to the page normally and see what the output is. ie. www.site.com/folder/dayPower.php?choice=2010-12-02

Comment: I get nothing... an empty div, and when trying to go to the page url it is as white as snow... blank

Comment: Try commenting everything out and just do `echo 'Choice:'.$_GET['choice'];`

Comment: Been trying thar and print_r with no result... if I remove the <? ?> I get something in the div

Comment: above is the datPower.php with the GET where the POST was... but it is the same result

Comment: What version of php are you using? Can it `echo` anything at all?

Comment: The webHost is running php 5.2.13... as for the echo, I get an empty div.

Comment: Just get it to work by going directly to it. Don't worry about the divs for now.

Comment: What do you mean by "going directly to it"

Comment: www.site.com/folder/dayPower.php?choice=2010-12-02

Comment: If you mean to go to the url, then that would be that the php file result is  '; ?> and nothing I do is changing that. The code being used right now with this result is seen at http://pastie.org/1341230

Comment: OK... yes, I know your meaning... http://localhost/monitor/dayPower.php?choice=2010-12-02 the result is.... '; ?>

Comment: @hkalan2007 - That's odd. Try just putting `<?php echo 'test'; ?>`

Comment: Sitting here.. looking at the code, I see that the php starts <? and then the next line starts $choice.... I added php to the start so it is <?php... it works now. I was so focused on the other parts I was overlooking the simple and basics... I feel really stupid now

Comment: @hkalan2007 - I noticed that but it should be a legitimate opening tag. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) (Example 2). I'm pretty sure it's been years since that wasn't supported in php. Maybe you have some kind of setting disabled for it. Anyways, does all your stuff work now?

Comment: The values are loading perfectly in each div. I am still working on getting the php files for the HighCharts graphs to load. I think my problem here is how I sort the sql data for the chart.

Comment: @hkalan2007: You should consider using JSON to send the data. Then you wouldn't have to worry about the order of the data you're sending back. You could even sort it with JavaScript.

Comment: I am trying to understand how JSON works, but it is really new to me.

Comment: Thanks to everyone's examples and input, I have everything working. Now I will try to put all 6 php files into 1 and see how json can make just one call... Again I thank everyone for their assistance ! Cheers